# Proving $f^{n} - (f+g)^{n} = -(f+\theta g)^{n-1}g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,g $ be arbitrary functions and i will settle for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Is the equality

$$ f^{n} - (f+g)^{n} = -(f+\theta g)^{n-1}g ~~ \text{ for some } \theta \in (0,1) $$ true? I tried it for $n=1,2,3$ and seems to hold true.

I tried to prove it by induction and by the mean value theorem but I failed. I am most likely missing some trick. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you are missing  a fator of $n$ on RHS. MVT for $x^{n}$  gives the answer. Any number between $f$ and $f+g$ is of the type $f+\theta g$ with $0<\theta <1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oops yes I see it now ,thanks !

Comment: Let $f, g$ be constant functions such that $f \equiv 1$ and $g\equiv 10^{-10}$.
Then there does not exit such $\theta \in (0,1)$ that satisfies the equality for $n>1$.